# MultipleOutputs map reduce does not work

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

I'm trying to write (key and value) to different files from reducer, but I got just one output file of keys and values.

```
 public static class Reduce
   extends Reducer<Text,Text,Text,Text> {
  private MultipleOutputs <Text,Text>mos;
@Override
protected void setup(Context context) throws IOException,           InterruptedException {      
    super.setup(context);
}
public void reduce(Text key, Text values, Context context ) throws IOException, InterruptedException {      
     mos.write(key.toString(),values, key); }  

@Override
    protected void cleanup(Context context) throws IOException,
            InterruptedException {
        super.cleanup(context);
    }   
}// end Reducer
```

// Driver program: it contains multiple outs

```
    job.setMapperClass(Map.class);
    job.setReducerClass(Reduce.class);
    job.setCombinerClass(Reduce.class);
    job.setInputFormatClass(TextInputFormat.class);
    job.setOutputFormatClass(TextOutputFormat.class);
    // set output key type   
    job.setOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
    // set output value type
    job.setOutputValueClass(Text.class);
    //set the HDFS path of the input data
    FileInputFormat.addInputPath(job, new Path(otherArgs[0]));
    // set the HDFS path for the output
    FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job, new Path(otherArgs[1]));
   //multiple output files
    MultipleOutputs.addNamedOutput(job, "express", TextOutputFormat.class, Text.class, Text.class);
```

Comment: What was the name of the generated output file?

Answer (score 0):

The `write` method of the `MultipleOutputs` class have three signatures, as shown below.

```
write(KEYOUT key, VALUEOUT value, String baseOutputPath) 
           Write key value to an output file name.

write(String namedOutput, K key, V value) 
          Write key and value to the namedOutput.

write(String namedOutput, K key, V value, String baseOutputPath) 
           Write key and value to baseOutputPath using the namedOutput
```

It seems that you're using the second one, but changing the key and value parameters. Also, I do not know the behaviour of this method if you pass the entire values `Iterable`.

As a suggestion, you can use the third signature, which is simpler, since you don't need do call `addNamedOutput` and can just write to any `baseOutputPath`.

For example:

```
mos.write(key, value, "express");
```